# Laravel paginate on top of intersect method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following DB query in Laravel.

```
    $filteredBundles = $bundlesByPublisher->intersect($bundlesByPublication);
```

I need to bring `paginate` method on `filteredBundles` variable.

`bundlesByPublisher` returns a DB query with method `get()` and similar is the case with `bundlesByPublication`.

Is there any way to bring pagination to this intersection?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Collection doesn't have `paginate()` method, but if you want paginate your collection, you can try

```
$paginator = new Paginator($filteredBundles, 15); // 15 is items per page
```

But it isn't a good performance when you have many records on database. Best choice is don't use intersect on returned collection, instead you filter in your query.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use the normal `paginate()` method on the intersection because `paginate()` operates on database queries and `intersect()` is a Collection.

What you can (and *should*) do is paginate the database results. In your case, this can be done by adding a `whereIn()` clause to a database query and giving it an array of IDs from the intersecting list.

Comment: Thanks @travis. but i got a better solution and i am posting here as the answer

Comment: @KevinRED if you include your full controller I can show what I mean with a specific example

Answer (score 0):

I created a private function of sort to which i will pass the `$filteredBundles->toArray()`

output.

```
private function _getPaginatedItems($items): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
        $perPage = 10;
        $currentItems = array_slice($items, $perPage * ($currentPage - 1), $perPage);

        $paginatedItems = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentItems, count($items), $perPage, $currentPage, ['path' => request()->url(), 'query' => request()->query()]);
        return $paginatedItems;
    }
```

this creates a `pagination` instance and works perfectly fine.